Ramps under front wheels, concrete pavers as risers under rear wheels
2010 Silverado 1500; 4wd; extended cab; 5,000 lbs
I'm repairing the truck's rocker panels, so I need to raise the truck so that I can work underneath the cab.
I've put plastic ramps under the front wheels and concrete pavers under the rear wheels.

The pavers are 4 inches high in total.
The driveway is on a slight incline, roughly a 1ft drop over 20ft towards the rear of the truck.
The truck is in 2WD mode.
The emergency brake is engaged.
I stood at the side of the truck and pushed it back and forth to test its stability. I didn't see any obvious problems.


Are there any safety issues with this approach?

A traffic cone or triangle reflector in the street while you're under the truck would prompt passing drivers to give the tail end a wider berth.

If the drive slopes as we see, wouldn't swapping everything (vehicle, paviours and ramps) so that the front of the vehicle is on the right, result in a more level vehicle? Then there will be less danger of rolling into the street.
